# I've asked some questions on here, figured it out and I want to share my data. Where?

Tags: discussion

I see quite often (maybe because I am searching for it) people recommending Geonames for postal code data, etc. I've taken data from Geonames and a few other places and spent some time cleaning it up. I found that quite a bit of the data in Geonames is outdated/incorrect. So far I've only done this for the United States, but I'd like to share my data. I was thinking about adding an answer to each question where someone mentions Geonames, but that seems like a long process. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say you want to share your data, what do you mean by "data"? What amount of data would it be?

Comment: By geonames for postal data, are you just talking about [Metropolitan Service Area](http://www.census.gov/population/metro/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding an answer to each question where someone mentions Geonames seems like a bad idea to me - disruptive and likely to get spam flags.

How about ask and answer your own question, then consider adding comment to a selection of other posts linking to your answer?